# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator registry value returned in base64

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

My dev conf : Win2010, WSO2 EI 6.4.0, linux for data store.

I defined a registry entry, named "sourcefileURI" for storing source filepath. The media type I chose is "text/plain" and I store a path like : "/home/wso2/data/in"
When accessing this registry value from a inbound endpoint vfs config, I'm using the following code :

```
<parameter key="conf:/repository/transports/vfs/telco1/sourcefileURI" name="transport.vfs.FileURI"/>
```

This is working - almost - fine. I mean the value is returned but in base64.
I was expecting, since I chose media = "text/plain", to have the normal string returned.

The string is well returne - in plain text and not encoded - when I swap media to nothing/void. But this is not something I want to last in my project.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong / don't understand here ?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1).Check the message builder and formatter you are using in conf/axis2.xml.Try to change the message builder and formatter for text/plain.

2) Otherwise simple solution is to use the xpath function `base64Decode(string encodedValue)`.

3) Otherwise Use script mediator to decode the string or use class mediator.

4) Otherwise use the following link https://ajanthane.blogspot.com/2017/05/accessing-modifying-payload-in.html, in which explains how to create a custom synapse handlers.